# My array isn't retaining its values outside the while loop?

Tags: java

I'm testing to see if my array list has retained the values from my text file and when I print the array outside the while loop to check this I only get the last value (20141013) from the file. When I print the for loop inside the while loop I get the list line by line. The problem is I have to now take that array, remove anything that isn't 8 digits print it, take the values that are 8 digits print it and then sort that and print it but I don't think my array is retaining those values. How can I make sure my array is filled with the correct values? I don't have to validate any of the dates.

> ```
> 20141003
> 20131105
> 19990205
> 20080304,20080305,20080306
> 19990206,hello,20141001,200003
> 20050505
> July
> November,August
> 19640503
> 19980707
> 19642199
> 20141013
> ```

```
import java.util.*;

public class Tokens1 {
    public static TextFileInput myFile;
    public static StringTokenizer myTokens;
    public static String[] list;
    public static String line;

    public static void main(String[] args) {

            myFile = new TextFileInput("project1.txt");

            while ((line = myFile.readLine()) != null) {
                myTokens = new StringTokenizer(line, ",");
                list = new String[myTokens.countTokens()];

                int i = 0;

                while (myTokens.hasMoreTokens()) {
                    list[i] = myTokens.nextToken();
                    i++;
                } //while

            } //while

            for (int j = 0; j < list.length; j++)
                System.out.println(list[j]);
        } //main
}
```

Comment: For each line of the text file, you're reinitializing i to 0 and making list the length of the number of tokens. So for each line you read, you're wiping out your previous work.

Comment: what could i do to stop that from happening?

Comment: Jean Logeart's answer is good. Try that solution. Basically, you need to initialize your list before the loop. Add to it (without resetting a counter) in the loop, then read it out after the loop.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You reassign your `list` array within the loop. Therefore only the last read line is contained in it.

You want to add elements to your list:

```
public static List<String> list = new ArrayList<>();

// in the while loop
for(String s : line.split(",")){
    list.add(s);
}
```

Now `list` contains all the strings, and you can print them outside the while loop doing:

```
for(String s : list) {
    System.out.println(s);
}
```

Edit using `StringTokenizer`:

```
// in the while loop
myTokens = new StringTokenizer(line, ",");
while(myTokens.hasMoreTokens()){
    list.add(myTokens.nextToken());
}
```

Comment: is there no way to do this with what i currently have using a string tokenizer? I know I could use a split but what about with a string tokenizer?

Comment: i used your method instead but i should be able to remove anything that isnt 8 digits and sort that moving forward right? Also the array is s or list? Because what i want to do now remove anything that isnt a 8 digit number into a separate array.

Comment: Also i can't seem to get the length of the array?

Answer (score 1):

Jean gave you the answer for you question, but i just need to add something :

```
while ((line = myFile.readLine()) != null) {
   while ((line = myFile.readLine()) != null) {
     ...
   }
}
```

YOU WILL NEVER WORK on the FIRST line of your file.

You read a line from your file, then you read one more line before doing anything with the first one, you probably need to get rid of the second while. Unless you want to ignore the first line on purpose.
:)